# is it possible to isolate and pair electromagnetic interaction?

Tags: electromagnetism

is it possible for two electromagnets to interact each other, ie. repulsive or attractive forces to be exerted to each other, without being exerted to other metallic items or other electromagnetic devices close by? Similar to bluetooth that pairs two devices without other being possible to interfere, but not for electromagnetic signals, but for electromagnetic forces induced.

Comment: Not unless the the other object is not ferromagnetic.  (Wood or aluminum, for example)

Comment: Not really, even though you could play some interesting tricks with AC fields and the shape of the magnets.

Comment: It isn't obvious to e what you are asking. If you're asking whether two electromagnets can exert a force on each other the answer is obviously yes because they will interact like two dipoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Bluetooth devices do in fact interfere with one another, just that the interference is not significant, and the communication protocols of the devices make it seem like they don't (i.e. my moving of my BT mouse does not move the cursor on your screen which is paired to your BT mouse)

You can isolate the system by putting the two electromagnets inside what is called a "Faraday's Cage" so that their main interaction is with each other. Anything outside the cage won't be able to "see" them.